# How can I change the comma separating two currencies in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string value:
let x = '$2,500,$3,500'

What would be the best way in JavaScript to return

x = '$2,500|$3,500'

to the user?

I have tried messing around with some regex but am unsure how to either capture or ignore the numeric value in between the $ and ,

I feel like there has to be a simple way of doing this that I am missing. Please let me know if you need any more details and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really fix the source where that string is coming from. Using a comma for two different things sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-word-boundary `\B`

```
 let result = str.replace(/,\B/g, '|');
```

That matches between two characters of the `\W` character class (that contains `,` and `$`). Note that it matches also between two characters of the `\w` class.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a looking ahead and replace the comma, followed by dollar sign.

```js
const
    replace = string => string.replace(/,(?=\$)/g, '|'),
    string = '$2,500,$3,500';

console.log(replace(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regex:

```js
x = '$2,500,$3,500'
let res = x.replace(",$", "|$");
console.log(res)
```

And if you have multiple values:

```js
x = '$2,500,$3,500,$123,456'
let res = x.replaceAll(",$", "|$");
console.log(res)
```